# how to replace block in output in magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I need to render products list page with custom ids which should be passed like
`http://mymagentostore.com/?ids=1,2,3,4,5` (or any other controller action instead of `cms_index_index`)

For this purpose, I am observing `layout_generate_blocks_after` event and want to change block from `cms_page` to my custom block in layout object.

I am trying this code in my observer:

```
public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $layout = $data['layout'];
        $block  = $layout->createBlock('\Company\Module\Block\CustomList');
        $layout->getBlock('cms_page')->append($block);
      }
```

But I cant see that `\Company\Module\Block\CustomList` block `toHtml` method is calling, why ?